# Sum of different table counts

Tags: mysql-5.5, count, sum

I have 2 different query and i want to summarize their count in other query like this:

```
    select a,((select count(id) from foo) + (select count(id) from bar)) 
    as 'alpha' from beta;
```

Is there a way to do it on mysql?

Comment: I would think that your query should work as specified.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

It worked as,

```
select a,(select (select count(id) from foo) + (select count(id) from bar)) 
as 'alpha' from beta;
```